# Can you pass options to ListObjects implicitly in C++?

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need to be able to pass a variety of Options to `ListObjects()`, such as `MaxResults()`, `Prefix()` and `StartOffset()`.

The combination of Options may differ on each `ListObjects()` call, so is there a struct or object I can initialise Options in and pass to ListObjects?

For example:

```
struct/object opts;
opts.MaxResults = 100;
opts.Prefix = "test-";
opts.StartOffset = "test-1";

client->ListObjects(bucket, opts);
```

**EDIT:**

I have an options struct:

```
struct list_objects_options {
    std::optional<gcs::MaxResults> count;
    std::optional<gcs::Delimiter> filter;
};
```

And I have a number of overloaded functions for different option inputs:

```
list_objects(std::size_t count, std::string filter) {
    list_objects_options opts;
    opts.count = gcs::MaxResults(count);
    opts.filter = gcs::Delimiter(filter);
    return list_objects(opts);
}
list_objects(std::string filter) {
    ...
}
```

Which call into:

```
list_objects(list_objects_options opts) {
    google::cloud::StatusOr<gcs::ListObjectsReader> response = client->ListObjects(m_bucket, opts);
}
```

However, using CMake to build I get an error for *no matching function call to ‘google::cloud::storage::v2_14::internal::GenericRequest<...>::set_option(list_objects_options&)’*

Comment: _"is there a struct..."_ - Not defined in the standard library, but you seem to have it almost defined already. What seems to be the problem with your `struct`?

Comment: Passing in a user-defined ```struct``` to ```ListObjects()``` results in errors. The ```struct list_objects_options``` contains ```google::cloud::storage``` types, however the error message is: ```note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'list_objects_options' to 'google::cloud::storage::v2_14::CustomHeader'```

Comment: Instead of trying to describe what it looks like, please provide the definitions of `ListObjects` and the options in a [mre] that you put in your question (not here in the comments section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Google Cloud Storage C++ SDK, any default initialized "options" have no effect.  Something like this should work:

```cpp
namespace gcs = google::cloud::storage;

struct list_object_options {
  gcs::Prefix prefix;
  gcs::Delimiter delimiter;
  gcs::MaxResults max_results; // rarely useful.
};

void F(gcs::Client c, std::string const& bucket, list_object_options o) {
  for (auto&& object : c.ListObjects(bucket, o.prefix, o.delimiter, o.max_results)) {
     // Do stuff with `object`
   }
}

void G() {
  auto client = gcs::Client();
  list_object_options o; // default initialized options have no effect
  o.prefix = "my-prefix";
  F(client, "my-bucket", o);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do however require the list_object_options variables to be std::optional<>. ListObjects() throws std::bad_optional_access if option is unset and passed to function, how can you get around this?

Comment: First, something like `client.ListObjects(b, gcs::Delimiter())` has exactly the same behavior as `client.ListObjects(b)`.  Wrapping a `gcs::Delimiter()` in a `std::optional<>` is overkill.  It is close to using  `std::optional<std::optional<std::string>>`, you can, but are you sure you need to?

If you must wrap the GCS options with `std::optional`: you could do something like `c.ListObjects(bucket, o.prefix.value_or(gcs::Prefix()), o.delimiter.value_or(gcs::Delimiter()), ...)`.